# Why Gurobi generates slack variables?

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi

I have the following LP:

```
max -x4-x5-x6-x7
s.t x0+x1+x4=1
    x2+x3+x5=1
    x0+x2+x6=1
    x1+x3+x7=1
```

Gurobi gives me the following base `B=[1,0,2,10]`, in my model I have 8 variables and `rank(A)=4`, but in the base I have variable x10. My question is, why Gurobi generates slack variables even with rank(A)=4? And how to get an optimal base that contains only the original variables (variables from x0 to x7)?

Comment: This question belongs on or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is degenerate. There are multiple optimal bases that give the same primal solution. In other words, some variables are basic at bound. This happens a lot in practice and you should not worry about that.

To make things more complicated: there are also multiple optimal primal solutions; so we say that we have both primal and dual degeneracy.

*My question is, why Gurobi generates slack variables even with rank(A)=4?*

The LP problem, for solvers like Gurobi (i.e. not a tableau solver), has n structural variables and m logical variables (a.k.a. slacks). The slack variables are implicit, they are not "generated" (in the sense that the matrix A is physically augmented with an identity matrix). Again, this is not something to worry about.

*And how to get an optimal base that contains only the original variables (variables from x0 to x7)?*

Well, this is an optimal basis. So why would Gurobi spend time and do more pivots to try to make all slacks non-basic? AFAIK no solver would do that. They treat structural and logical variables as equals.

It is not so easy to force variables to be in the basis. A free variable will most likely be in the (optimal) basis (but no 100% guarantee). You can also specify an advanced basis for Gurobi to start from. In the extreme: if this advanced basis is optimal (and feasible) Gurobi will not do any pivots.

I believe this particular problem has 83 optimal (and feasible) bases. Only one of them has all slacks NB. I don't think it is easy to find this solution, even if you would have access to a Simplex code and can change it so (after finding an optimal solution) it continues pivoting slacks out of the basis. I think you would need to enumerate optimal bases (explicitly or implicitly).

Comment: Thank you fro your response. I tried to specify an advanced basis for Gurobi by:                         `for(size_t j=4;j<8;++j){
    error = GRBsetintattrelement(model, GRB_INT_ATTR_VBASIS, j, 0); 
      if (error) goto QUIT;}`  but Gurobi still give me the base with index 10, in my algorithm I need to have an optimal base with the original variables

Answer (score 0):

Slack variables are generated because it is necessary to solve for a dual linear programming model and reduction bound. A complementary slackness; Si would also be generated.
Moreover, X0 forms a branch for linear independence of a dual set-up. X0 has the value of 4, slack variables are generated from the transformation of the basis; where the rank is given, to the branch X0 for linear independence.
A reduction matrix is formed to find the value of X10 which has the value of 5/2.
This helps to eliminate X10 inorder to get an optimal base from the reduction matrix.